# What are the possible words or word phrases which can describe Friendship between two persons?

Tags: synonyms

### Purpose:

I'm trying to build a computer program / a database where a User (from various set-ups) can have options (all possible meaningful semantically correct manner) to define/describe a relation (Bi-directional or Uni-directional) between two persons. I hope to gather an Exhaustive Data with the contributions of the Community Members.

### Question

What are the possible words or phrases which can describe Friendship between two persons (Male to Male or Female)? If any words or phrase is Gender-specific or Situation-specific, please mention.

### Example:

Person A  - is a friend of - Person B.

Person A  - is a buddy of - Person B.

Person A  - is a chum of - Person B.

Person A  - is a pal of - Person B.

Person A  - is a mate of - Person B.

------It is not necessary that it should have -is a- or -has a- or such thing should be the part of relationship description.

### Subsequent Question

What are the possible words or phrases which can describe/indicate the degree /depth or level of Friendship between two persons?

### Example

Person A - is an acquaintance of - Person B.

Person A - is a soulmate of - Person B.

(Male to Male or Female) If any words or phrase is dependent on Gender of either side of the relationship, or any situation-specific, please mention.

### Example:

(1) A Class Teacher can describe/record a Relationship between the two classmates.

Smith -fonds of- Allen.

(2) A Jailor can describe /record a Relationship between the two prisoners.

Prisoner No.234 - is a crony to - Prisoner No. 45.

or

Prisoner No.234 - are cronies - Prisoner No. 45.

Comment: How about 'platonic'?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "companions," "comrades," "confidants/confidantes," (distinction explained [here)](https://grammarist.com/usage/confidant-confidante/), most of the top synonyms [here.](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/friend/synonyms) Some of these are verging on the romantic side, though. I think that Google would be sufficient as well, as this seems to just synonyms.

I am kind of confused about your subsequent question, however. It seems that you are speaking of romantic relationships in a very roundabout manner, either that or that is not what you mean at all. If you are, in fact, talking about relationships of that kind, there is always "crush," "lover," "partner," or "spouse" if married to be gender-neutral. If you mean just a deeper level of friendship, you could use "best friends" or "close friends."

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ I definitely searched synonyms through the online thesaurus, dictionaries. But no dictionary holds the data in an exhaustive manner or entirety. I want to accumulate all the possible variants the different People use in general. No one can list them all single-handedly, will need help of many people.